# How To Place a Trigger On the Change In the "Application.EnableEvents" Property

Tags: excel, vba, triggers

Is there a way I could run a specific macro whenever the "Application.EnableEvents" value is changed?
By putting this in a SUB:

```
Debug.Assert Application.EnableEvents = True
```

I get a break point whenever Application.EnableEvents has the value False within that sub, but I'm looking to invalidate a ribbon control when this happens so the users get notified.

Ideally I'm searching for a more general trigger that put something in every sub, because I have hundreds of subroutines and most of them switch enable events, but I'm open to any suggestion.

My goal is this: I have a very complex Excel template that is mostly dependent on EnableEvents being on, and if users get an error, they continue working as if nothing happened, and the template does not work as intended. EnableEvents needs to be OFF when automatic values are filled in, like restoring defaults. I'm trying to create a flag in my system that tells the users that they need to restore functionality before going forward.

Comment: What do you mean by `I get a break point whenever Application.EnableEvents has the value False within that sub`?  Regardless, it sounds like you have another issue/root-cause that should be addressed instead of making your code *even more complex, to work around your workbook's errors*. (an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378))   This is not a proper way to introduce error handling. Its sounds like you should back up and describe the *actual* problems.

Comment: Make one Sub in which you put EnableEvents = false and invalidating of your Ribboncontrol and one Sub you put EnableEvents = True and invalidating your RibbonControl. (call these subs in all your macro's with event-toggling in it) As ashleedawg already pointed out put proper error-handling in, which triggers the latter Sub.  As a workaround you could use the commandbarsonupdate-event to see if events are on/off, (but definitively not the way to go)